# autocomplete returns undefined data

Tags: django, jquery

to have autocompletion on an input,I do this:
in `views.py`:

```
def getpositions(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        query = request.GET.get("term", "")
        positions=Position.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        results = []
        for position in positions:
            position_json={}
            position_json['name']=position.name
            results.append(position_json)
        data=simplejson.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'error'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

in `template`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#positions").autocomplete({
                        source: "{% url CompanyHub.views.getPositions%}",
                        success: function( data ) {
                                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                        return {
                                            label: item.name,
                                            value: item.name
                                        }
                                    }));
                                },
                        minLength: 2,
                      });
                });
```

and `#positions` is : `<input type="text" id="positions" />`

every thing is ok,but it just show `Undefined` instead of showing list of results,I tryed many things but no way!!

Comment: you could add a `debugger` instruction and check what `data` contains

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI autocomplete from here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/, then it doesn't have a  success option.

Comment: Claudio Redi : I get this json in respone : Object { name="blah blah"}

Comment: Joy I'm using the same,what's the problem?what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI autocomplete doesnt have a `success` option you are using to format your data. Check the option list here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ . Instead You can use a callback function for `source` option and handle your own ajax call yourself and format data like you want.

```
$("#positions").autocomplete({                    
       source: function( req,resp ) {
         $.get("{% url CompanyHub.views.getPositions%}",
              {term:req.term},function(data){
                   resp( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                        return {
                                            label: item.name,
                                            value: item.name
                                        };
                                    })
                             );
                           });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            });
```

Comment: Are parantheses correct?I get error on them and don't know what's the problem!

Comment: @Asma, there were problem in parentheses earlier, but I fixed those it should work fine now. Check and let me know.

Comment: tnx a million but It has problem yet!!

Comment: in lines 9,10,11 of your answer it has problem with parantheses